# two row to one row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below.

```
customer_number      note       loayltystatus    Tier_code
123                  yes
123                  yes        1                 
123                                               1
```

How to combine one row from two row as above in select statement?

EG:

```
customer_number      note       loayltystatus    Tier_code
    123                  yes    1                1
```

Comment: You have 3 rows not 2 rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT customer_number, MAX(note),MAX(loyaltyStatus),MAX(Tier_code)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY customer_number
```

Comment: Good question. Actually no, because then it would treat the "yes" notes as one group and the blank notes as another. Then you would have two rows

Comment: You're right @Stephan,  looking closer to the example output note would not be a grouped field

Answer (score 0):

I use the SQL Server `FOR XML` statement in order to combine multiple rows into a single row. This will account for any number of rows with different values in each.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t
CREATE TABLE #t
(
    customer_number INT,
    note            NVARCHAR(100),
    loyaltystatus   INT,
    Tier_code       INT
)

INSERT INTO #t SELECT 123, N'yes', NULL, NULL

INSERT INTO #t SELECT 123, N'yes', 1, NULL

INSERT INTO #t SELECT 123, N'yes', NULL, 1

INSERT INTO #t SELECT 123, N'something else', NULL, NULL


SELECT
    customer_number,
        STUFF(
            (SELECT DISTINCT N',' + note
               FROM #t AS s               
               WHERE s.customer_number = t.customer_number
               ORDER BY N',' + note
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.',N'nvarchar(max)')
        ,1,1,N'') AS note,
        STUFF(
            (SELECT DISTINCT N',' + CAST(loyaltystatus AS NVARCHAR(100))
               FROM #t AS s               
               WHERE s.customer_number = t.customer_number
               ORDER BY N',' + CAST(loyaltystatus AS NVARCHAR(100))
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.',N'nvarchar(max)')
        ,1,1,N'') AS loyaltystatus,
        STUFF(
            (SELECT DISTINCT N',' + CAST(Tier_code AS NVARCHAR(100))
               FROM #t AS s               
               WHERE s.customer_number = t.customer_number
               ORDER BY N',' + CAST(Tier_code AS NVARCHAR(100))
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.',N'nvarchar(max)')
        ,1,1,N'') AS Tier_code
FROM
    #t AS t
GROUP BY customer_number
```